# React: I have some error with edit state from reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My Source: https://codesandbox.io/s/x91zl9v78p

I try to edit title and content, but first time, content is not modified, only title is modified.

From the second it works well.

Why this error occurs?

reducers.js :

```
case UPDATE_POST:
  return state.map(
    post => (post.id === action.id ? Object.assign({}, post, action) : post)
  );
```

And, Is there a way I want to use the spread operator without using object.assign?

Comment: Using your example on codesandbox I can't see a problem. The code works well.

Comment: Weird, I created an item an then edited both, `title` and `content` and both updated successfully. No issue faced

Comment: For example, I add title: 123, content: 456 and edit both, only title updated. content is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because your Item component's constructs with an empty string, so when you edit the title input the state is updated, and if you do not edit the content input it will remain empty.

components/List/items.jsx

```
class Item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isEdit: false,
      title: this.props.title,
      content: this.props.content
    };
  }
  //...
}
```

And to avoid Object.assign

reducers/post.jsx

```
case UPDATE_POST:
  return state.map(
    post => (post.id === action.id ? { ...post, ...action } : post)
  );
```

This will clone `post` props, and merge `action` props.

https://codesandbox.io/s/5xpnm9yrrx

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing initial values for title and content in props you need to sync initical `Item` component state values to props by implementing

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps({ title, content }) {
    return {
      title, content
    }
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7m4z538x96)

Otherwise, if user doesn't touch a field (say for content) the code will use default state value which is an empty string.

> And, Is there a way I want to use the spread operator without using
>   object.assign?

```
case UPDATE_POST:
  return state.map(
    post => (post.id === action.id ? {...post, ...action} : post)
  );
```

Also by spreading entire action into the post you are polluting post object with additional attribute `type`. Consider using `payload` object instead to pass updated post.

```
export function updatePost(id, title, content) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_POST,
    payload: {
      id,
      title,
      content
    }
  };
}
```

and then spread the payload

```
case UPDATE_POST:
  return state.map(
    post => (post.id === action.payload.id ? {...post, ...action.payload} : post)
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Because in item.jsx file `this.state.title` and `this.state.content` are updated only when input get's changed if either of the input is not changed then either of `this.state.title or this.state.content` are empty strings. After adding an item to the list `this.props.title` and `this.props.content` are available but `this.state.title` and `this.state.content` initially are defined as "" strings in the component. so insted of taking defaultvalue as this.props.tile and this.props.content, on edit set `this.state.title = this.props.title` and `this.state.content = this.props.content` then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Edit wqr4r0wnvw]

maybe by using it in the function args like this :

```
export default function Post(state = initialState, {type, ...post}) {

  switch (type) {

    case ADD_POST:
      return [ ...state, post ];

    case REMOVE_POST:
      return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== post.id);

    case UPDATE_POST:
      return state.map( p => (p.id === post.id ? post : p) );

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) But, content's empty string is still.